# TS832 audio-video transmitter lowers its input voltage

Tags: transmitter

I have a TS832 audio-video transmitter, and in its datasheet it says that the operating voltage is typically 12V, but can range from 7V to 16V. I am powering the transmitter with a 9V battery.
I am measuring the voltage between its DC IN (+) and its DC OUT (-) pins, and it's 5.1V. Shouldn't that be the same with the battery's voltage? There's nothing but cable between the pins and the battery terminals!

If I ignore this problem and connect everything else correctly (camera, receiver, antennas) and connect the receiver to a television, I see nothing. That's why I believe that this problem is why the whole system isn't working.

The transmitter also heats up quite quickly while it's operating, if that helps.

Comment: Your battery is dead. Or the device is dead and drawing too much current. The latter is supported by the device heating up.

Comment: How do you know 5.1V isn't teh battery's voltage under that load? It very well might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search for TS832 specs ([example here](https://www.getfpv.com/5-8ghz-32ch-a-v-600mw-video-transmitter-ts832-international-version.html)) shows its expected current draw is 600 mA. If you are using a "transistor radio" rectangular 9V battery like this

[image]

it isn't up to the task. Its total capacity of ~500 mAh would be drained in less than an hour. And its internal resistance will cause the output voltage to be significantly less than 9V, as you are measuring, and the circuit to not work.

You could use 6 AA cells in series. Those cells have 2400 mAh capacity, so might last 4 hours. Or you could use 2 LiPo cells in series, but you'll have to deal with recharging circuitry. As a beginner, I'd recommend sticking to the AA cells. You can get rechargeable AA cells and a commercial recharger. Good luck!